# db_select() on Drupal 7 - problem with field

Tags: php, database, drupal, drupal-7

I have a problem with below code:

```
db_select('field_data_commerce_price', 'f')->fields('f', 'commerce_price_amount')->execute()->fetchAssoc()
```

Error is: "TypeError: Argument 2 passed to SelectQuery::fields() must be of the type array, string given". Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is coming because you are giving a string as an argument in fields method change into array and the error will be resolved. Do something like below

```
  db_select('field_data_commerce_price', 'f')->fields('f', array('commerce_price_amount') )->execute()->fetchAssoc()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is pretty clear, the second argument on the fields method must be an array, try it this way:

```
db_select('field_data_commerce_price', 'f')->fields('f', ['commerce_price_amount'])->execute()->fetchAssoc()
```

Comment: Only on PHP5.4+